# How to connect to mysql with computer name in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to connect to mysql with my computer name as host.
I get this error :

> unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts

When i change the host with **localhost** or **127.0.0.1**. it's work fine.

I test the connection directly in mysql workbench with my computer name : COMP-18TN. MySQL Workbench could connect to that server. But not my c# code.

You find as bellow my code :

```
 string host = "COMP-18TN";
 string DatabaseName = "Cars_DB";
 string UserName ="root_name";
 string Password ="pass";
 string connString = string.Format("Server={0}; database={1}; UID={2}; password={3}",
                host, DatabaseName, UserName, Password);
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding an entry in your `hosts` file located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`:

`127.0.0.1   COMP-18TN`

This way your computer name will resolve to the local IP which you know works.